# Can you say "sur la reto" for something you found in the Internet?

Tags: prepositions

Is *Mi trovis ion **sur** la reto* a valid way to say that you found something in the Internet? Should prepositions such as *en* and *per* be prefered?

Answer (score 8):

Mi kutimas diri "en la reto", same kiel "en la libro"

Answer (score 6):

For sure *en la reto*.

A quick search of the Tekstaro only turns up one or two references to *sur la reto* and none of these are related to the internet.

To clarify the above. In the Tekstaro, there are the following references to *en la reto*:

- Six (6) from *Monato* - all six refer to the internet.
- Thirty three (33) from *La Ondo de Esperanto* - All the ones I've looked at closely refer to the internet.

Contrast this with ***sur*** la reto. There are only two hits **total**. Neither one has to do with the internet.

Further, there are two hits for ***en*** la interreto and none for *sur la interreto*.

So, based on my subjective impression of what expression is more common, the logic explained in other language, and actual usage as captured in the Tekstaro, my recommendation is for ***en*** la reto.

Comment: most of the books in Tekstaro were written before the internet existed so of course none of them are related to the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's interesting that this answer has gotten fewer upvotes and more down-votes (currently +2,-1) than mondano's answer which says the same thing with less justification. Would you like me to discuss the specific examples in the Tekstaro? My judgement is that they are indeed relevant to the question - and there are quite a few references to *en la reto* that are indeed related to the internet. For sure, the correct expression is ***en** la reto*

Comment: I downvoted when I realized the evidence was misleading.

Comment: I have added an explanation of what I found in my "quick search of the Tekstaro" - along with some information from a more detailed search. I hope this has convinced you to change your downvote to an upvote. (Currently +3, -1.) If not, please let me know what is missing.

Answer (score 2):

*Sur la reto* is perfectly fine. Just ask yourself whether the mental image is meaningful and unambiguous. If so, trust it.

---

This has been downvoted, so here's why it's correct: a *reto* is a net. Does a net have a surface? Yes it does, even as a figurative network, which is why an object caught in the net *(en)* is also on it *(sur)*. The Internet is a network on the surface of the Earth, and thus anything in the net can also be visualized as on it.

If the expression *[sur la reto](https://www.esperanto-usa.org/en/node/177)* is good enough for the skilled poet Steven Brewer, it should be good enough for anyone. And please note that the *Tekstaro* consists of material from before 2005, the bulk of it much older.

Comment: I would argue that the *reto* part of *interreto* is due to the net-like structure that is the wires that connects us all (or originally rather). If something is ‘on the internet’, it is in fact contained inside those wires (and transistors etc.) that make up the internet. Therefore, I think *en la reto* makes more sense.

Comment: My point is that both are valid; speakers' visualizations may differ.

Comment: Right, I see. To me *sur la reto* doesn't make much sense, but several languages seem to have an equivalent expression; I agree that it is fine. (I didn't downvote you by the way.)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is okay to say **sur** or **en**. I prefer saying **en** myself because the info is stored inside computers/servers.

Here are a few examples for **sur la reto**:

> Esperanto sur la reto https://www.esperanto-usa.org/en/node/177
>
> Rezultoj de KER-ekzamenoj jam aperas sur la reto! http://www.esperanto-mexico.org/eo/rezultoj-de-ker-ekzamenoj-jam-aperas-sur-la-reto
>
> ...ni klopodas pliigi nian prezenton sur la reto,... http://www.espero.com.cn/2014-02/24/content_31575257.htm

Here are some for **en la reto**

> Esperantaj vortaroj en la reto https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperantaj_vortaroj_en_la_reto
>
> Lerni Esperanton en la reto http://www.esperanto.net/veb/lerni.html
>
> La kaŝita katastrofo - Kontakto 2016:2 en la reto http://kontakto.tejo.org/2016/04/la-kasita-katastrofo-kontakto-20162-en.html

Answer (score 0):

Prepositions in Esperanto should be understood quite literally.

- ***en*** means, that something must be inside something. For instance *en la tablo* means, that there must be a drawer at bottom surface of the table to hold something or the thing is between the upper and lower surfaces of the tabletop. Being inside implies, that you usually cannot see it.
- ***sur*** means, that something lays on a surface. For instance *sur la tablo* means, that the thing is on the table, above the tabletop touching it. Being on implies, that you usually can see it.

While one can argue, that internet is a net with a surface, **on** which you can have/hang things, for most people the internet is more like a box or a drawer, **in** which you have things. For this later metaphor speaks the fact, that the content of the internet is not visible right by looking at your device (computer, tablet or a phone) unless you go and search for it. Contrast this to a street, the "content" is there in plain sight.